# How to call a variable from a php page to another?

Tags: php

I have the following codes:

```
$n = $totalMins/60;
    $whole = floor($n);
    $fraction = $n - $whole;

    $totalHrs += $whole;
    $totalMins = round($fraction*60);
    $total = "$totalHrs hours and $totalMins mins";
    $totalDeci = round($fraction, 2);

    $totalDeci += $totalHrs;
    $totalDeci = number_format($totalDeci, 2);
```

I want the $totalDeci to be called on another php page that I have. Is there a way for me to call it? I'm not really familiar with php.

Comment: it depends entirely on the structure of the site, where the code above gets called and where it is required again. You could set the variable in a session variable and that would make it easy

Answer (score 0):

Use [session variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).

```
Page1.php:
    <?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['your_variable'] = 'your_value';
    ?>

Page2.php:
    <?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['your_variable'];
    ?>

Page2.php will show: your_value
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use session as above example or use query string

```
index.php?id=101
$user_id=$_GET['id'];
echo "$user_id";
```